# How to pass dynamic url to template in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to create a template that receives a 'link_url' variable and I want to pass it a dynamic URL, like this one: {% url "app:genericlistmodel" model="model_handle" %}. This way I could modularize this template and save a lot of time.

**The main problem here** is that code like this "{% example %}" can not be inside the {% include %} tag, and I don't want to pass hardcoded url's.

**Things I've tried that are not working:**

```
{% include 'snippet.html' with link_url={% url "gepian:genericlistmodel" model="entrepreneurs" %} %}
```

---

```
{% url "gepian:genericlistmodel" model="entrepreneurs" %}
{% include 'snippet.html' with link_url=url %}
```

---

```
{% include 'snippet.html' with link_url=url "gepian:genericlistmodel" model="entrepreneurs" %}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: what do you want realy, where are you see that url can take model as parameter ?

Comment: Did you try using template filter?

Comment: @NathanIngram The url I want to pass takes an argument which is just a model handle. Example: /add/<entrepreneurs>/

If you think the question will be clearer without that I can remove it, but at the end of the day I will need to pass it.

Comment: @danish_wani Which filter exactly? The main problem here is that code like this "{% example %}" can not be inside the {% include %} tag, and I don't want to pass hardcoded url's.

Comment: You can use custom filter and pass model kwarg as filter's parameter and use reverse in the custom filter, i can you provide you the example if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template:

```
{% load custom_filters %}

{% include 'snippet.html' with link_url="entrepreneurs"|get_url %}
```

templatetags/custom_filters.py

```
from django import template
from django.urls import reverse
register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def get_url(argument):
    reverse("gepian:genericlistmodel" kwargs={'model': argument})
```